# Union All of one linked server in a With clause of query of one linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, linked-server, union-all

In a stored procedure, I have a few With clauses, of a query executed at linked server A:

```
DECLARE @myQuery VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @myQuery = 'SELECT * FROM (WITH 
   A AS (Select ... from ...),
   B AS (Select ... from ...),
   C AS (Select ... from ...)
   Select A., B., C.
   From A
   Join B On
   Join C On
')


INSERT INTO Table_A
EXEC (@myQuery) AT Linked_Server_A
```

Now I want to Union All a query executed at linked server B, with same structure, in the With clause B.
It shall look like:

```
DECLARE @myQuery VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @myQuery = 'SELECT * FROM (WITH 
   A AS (Select ... from ...),
   B AS (Select ... from ...
         UNION ALL
         Select ... from Openquery(linked server B, 'Select ... from...')),
   C AS (Select ... from ...)
   Select A., B., C.
   From A
   Join B On
   Join C On
')

INSERT INTO Table_A
EXEC (@myQuery) AT Linked_Server_A
```

I would like to know if there is a simple way to achieve this. Appreciate for your feedback.

Comment: Insert all linked server data into temp tables, then run your query on the temp tables.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (WITH...` isn't valid syntax. You define your CTEs at the *start* of the statement not in a derived table.

Comment: @ThomA, it might be valid query in the linked server. i think mysql supports this weird WITH construct for example

Comment: can't you do this as a UNION ALL of OPENQUERY calls instead of EXEC AT Server?

Comment: @siggemannen does MySQL support OPENQUERY? I thought that was SQL Server-specific?

Comment: @siggemannen Yes, this is through SQL Server

Comment: I mean doing two openqueries on the outside as a union